# getting the parent object from child object in nested objects from JSON with type script

Tags: json, angular, typescript, tree

Is it possible to get the parent object from a child object dynamically? Essentially, all I'm trying to accomplish is to dynamically retrieve the value of a property belonging to a child objects' parent. For example, in the following Json, I want to extract the driver of a particular car.:

```
   {
        "driver": [
            {
                "id": 1,       |
                "name": "Bob", |=> this is the parent
                "age": "34",   |
                "car": [
                    {
                        "make": "BMW",     |
                        "model": "3.20",   | this is the child
                        "colour": "Silver",|
                        "mileage": [
                            {
                                "total": "350523",
                                "year": [
                                    {
                                        "2011": "3535",
                                        "2012": "7852",
                                        "2013": "8045"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "month": [
                                    {
                                        "december": "966",
                                        "november": "546",
                                        "october": "7657"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
         }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: which is parent which is child. what you are exactly looking for??

Comment: Can you check the  question again ?? I clarified it

Comment: how are you going to get the parent component **driver** information. Where you are using it?

Comment: You want to find the parent using the child object?

Comment: Yes that's it, I want to get the parent using the child object

Comment: driver can have more than one car? will make be same for two driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using for loops:

```
for(let parent of data.driver) {
   for(let car of parent.car) {
      if(car.make === 'BMW') {
          // can do what you like with 'parent'
      }
   }
}
```

Using `filter()` or `find()` (standard javascript):

```
drivers_who_drive_bwm = data.driver.filter((parent) => {
    // find() will give -1, if no car was found that matched 
    //    car.make === 'BWM'
    return parent['car'].find((car) => car.make === 'BWM') !== -1
})
```

Also:

Your naming conventions are confusing. I would expect `driver.car` to be a single car, in your code it's array of cars. If it always contains single car, then it would be better not to use array. Same for `.driver`. Better key would be `.drivers` to indicate multiple drivers. (but maybe it is XML converted to json, in that case you are stuck with it?)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whatever strategy you choose, you will basically be iterating through and returning. So I feel the "best" strategy is using what you are most comfortable with.

Typescript is just Javascript. So if you are comfortable with a Javascript-ey "functional programming" way of doing things you can use Array map & filter.

You of course will have to deal with application specific logic you have not specified like "What happens when the same make/model exists across different drivers?".

If you are not comfortable with functional programming you can always build up a series of maps and then perform lookups.

But if you need to get it right, always do what you are comfortable doing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, an Object reference is just a memory location. there is no concept of parents comes here. its may not have any parent (just a logical thinking as parent, so may not any other object have property having reference to it), or may a lot of object have referred to same memory location (i.e. multiple parent by your logic).

1> So Either you can put parent reference to each child element programitically. Note, here you cannot do by parsing a JSON string, because its contains only JSON data, not reference as parse-able.

2> Or else Try to find out the driver object (i.e. parent object) having child object which contains your value according to your condition. you ca use `filter` , `map` of array functions in javascript to do so. but whatever you are doing is just iterating and find. in that case `underscrore` js will be a good library to use